# Weird message (MacOS 14): "-macosx_version_min has been renamed to -macos_version_min"

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I keep getting this:

```
-macosx_version_min has been renamed to -macos_version_min
```

anytime I compile anything. Any reason why? Can I prevent it?

Comment: What are you compiling?

Comment: hello world @IconDaemon. `gcc hello.c` (not `clang`, real `gcc`) -- but it also showed when I compiled `emacs` with `clang`.

Comment: Did you update Xcode to the latest version?

Comment: Which version of gcc?

Comment: 13.1.0 @mmmmmm .

Comment: Yes @nohillside

Comment: Looks like a gcc bug see https://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-bugs@gcc.gnu.org/msg785716.html

Comment: Actually not a gcc bug - This is due to Xcode 15 using a new linker. The build scripts for some apps using gcc need to be changed to either use the old linker or some other change for the linker. I would answer but this has been closed (wrongly as there is enough info to know exactly the issue)

Comment: @mmmmmm Do you mind answering now? Would be worth an answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is a change  in Xcode 15.

My answer is from a quick google and seeing other bug reports on this issue however I haven't looked in enough detail to say more than the line above but I think the issue is Apple introduced a new linker (and also renamed the old one to classic which was already used)which has this change in flag.

gcc have also changed their code to fix this
[From the gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=110624)

> Darwin: Use -platform_version when available [PR110624].

> Later versions of the static linker support a more flexible flag to describe the OS, OS version and SDK used to build the code.  This replaces the functionality of '-mmacosx_version_min' (which is now deprecated, leading to the diagnostic described in the PR).

> We now use the platform_version flag when available which avoids the diagnostic.